# const char* to an of filename strings to read in 10 diffrent .pgm files to a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, iostream, ifstream

I have been struggling with this all day and I know that my mistake is a simple one but I cannot seem to overcome it. The goal of this is to read in 10 different portable graymap (pgm) files in succession into a 2D array `uchar images [img_size][imgNum]`. The first dimension being the actual image data, a 28x28 array that I read in linearly, and the second dimension being the image number out of ten. Portable graymap represents every pixel with a number x such that 0 < x < 255 that represents a scale of gray. To get it all to read and write correctly I first must read the image data in as an integer and then cast it to a unsigned char.

Okay so the problem I am having is specifically is here in my function

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < imgNum; i++){
    instream.open(filename[i]); //this does not work when called in main
```

... and implimented in main

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char* filename[10] ={"digit_00.pgm","digit_01.pgm","digit_02.pgm","digit_03.pgm","digit_04.pgm","digit_05.pgm","digit_06.pgm","digit_07.pgm","digit_08.pgm","digit_09.pgm"};
    uchar images[img_size][imgNum] ;
    readPGMImages(images, img_size , filename , imgNum);
```

I cannot for the life of me seem to get the compiler to view `filename[i]` where `i=1` as `instream.open("digit_00.pgm")`

Here is all of my code. I do need to operate within the stated parameters in readPGMImages. Meaning using anything but `const char * filename` will not work for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef unsigned char uchar ;
typedef unsigned int uint ;
using namespace std;
const int img_size = 784;
const int imgNum = 10;


void readPGMImages( uchar images [img_size][imgNum], int img_size ,
                    const char * filename[imgNum], int imgNum )
{
    uint holder[img_size][imgNum];
    int header;
    ifstream instream;
    for ( int i = 0; i < imgNum; i++){
        instream.open(filename[i]); //this does not work
        if (instream.fail()){
            cout << "failed to open" << endl;
            exit(1);}

        instream >> header >> header >> header >> header ;
        for (int j = 0; j < img_size ; j++){
                instream >> holder[j][i];
                holder[j][i] = static_cast<uchar>(holder[j][i]);
            images[j][i]=holder[j][i] ; //edited here
            cout << images[j][i] << endl;
                }
            instream.close() ; //edited here
            }
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char* filename[10] ={"digit_00.pgm","digit_01.pgm","digit_02.pgm","digit_03.pgm","digit_04.pgm","digit_05.pgm","digit_06.pgm","digit_07.pgm","digit_08.pgm","digit_09.pgm"};
//I believe I have a mistake above but I'm unsure 
    uchar images[img_size][imgNum] ;
    readPGMImages(images, img_size , filename , imgNum); //this is where I call the function

return 0;
}
```

I hope my post etiquette is okay.

Thank you!

Comment: Either move `ifstream instream;` inside the loop (so you have a new `ifstream` instance on each iteration), or else call `instream.close()` at the end of the loop. You are trying to open `instream` twice - the second attempt fails since the stream is already open.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you! Now it seems I have another issue because its printing unexpected characters instead of ones between 0 and 255 like expected. can you see any reason as to why that would be? I'm having trouble seeing the problem there

Comment: You read a number from the stream into `holder[j][i]`, then immediately overwrite it with the value of `images[j][i]` (which is uninitialized random garbage). Did you mean that assignment to go the other way, perhaps? It's unclear why you feel you need `holder` in the first place.

Comment: yes that is what I meant. I need to write to an `int` and then cast it to an `unsigned char`. It seems simply switching the two over the `=` sign didn't quite do it.

Comment: Well, edit the question to show what your code looks like now. I can't comment on what I can't see.

Comment: Added the code and put a `//edited here` next to it. also I define `Images` right before I use it as a parameter in `readPGMImages` in main. My logic is that `images` should be of type `uchar` and having type casted `holder` from `unit` to `uchar` should allow me to seamlessly set the values of `images` to those set in `holder`.

Comment: Since `images[j][i]` is now `char`, `cout << images[j][i]` will attempt to print it as a character, not as a number. In the same way that `cout << 'A'` prints `A` and not `65`. If you want to print integers, make it `cout << int(images[j][i])`

Comment: okay I have succeed in the task. thank you so much for your time!